# How to write/print a string to a new textfile in python?

Tags: python, string, file

I have a string within a variable and I want to write that variable to a text file in it's printed form I.E.
My obvious guess was to do this:

```
'filename'.write(string_variable)
```

But its giving me this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#14>", line 1, in <module>
main('studyguide.txt','decrypted.txt')
File "C:/Users/Casey/Documents/New folder/pa11.py", line 45, in main
writefile.write(finalstr)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'write'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `open("filename","w+")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to [`open`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) a file, and use `file.write`:

```
with open(writefile, 'w') as f:
    f.write(finalstr)
```